# Superfish and WordPress: Active Color Problem

Tags: css, menus

Take a look at: http://www.themeforward.com/demo2.  When I hover over a menu item with a sub-menu, like 'Templates', and mouse over sub-menu items the background color stays the same as it should... but the hover color of the text does not.

How do I make the font color remain the same while scrolling through the sub-menu?  I've Googled all over for this and can't find a solution.  The Superfish site does not provide sample CSS for this issue and provides no answer on the matter.  **I usually wouldn't post this as a question here since it is a CSS question, but I believe it may also be related to a WordPress' current category feature.**

The background color is achieved with this CSS, but the font color is not behaving in the same manner:

```
.sf-menu > li:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHover,
.sf-menu > li a:focus, .sf-menu > li a:hover, .sf-menu > li a:active {
    background:     #CFDEFF;
    color:          #222;
    outline:        0;
}
```

Below you will find the entire CSS:

```
.sf-menu {
    z-index: 900;
    font-size:13px
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color:          #FFF;
    text-decoration:none
}
.sf-menu li {
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
    z-index: 900
}
.sf-menu li li {
    z-index: 900;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#DDD;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    background:     #DDD;
    margin:0;
    z-index: 900
}
.sf-menu > li:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHover,
.sf-menu > li a:focus, .sf-menu > li a:hover, .sf-menu > li a:active {
    background:     #CFDEFF;
    color:          #222;
    outline:        0;
}

.sf-menu .current-post-ancestor a, .sf-menu .current-menu parent a, .sf-menu .current-page-ancestor a, .sf-menf .current-category-ancestor a, .sf-menu .active_category a, .sf-menu .current-menu-item a { color:#000 }

ul .sub-menu { border:1px solid #DCDCDC }
ul li .sub-menu a { color:#666!important; font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; padding:5px!important }
.sf-menu > li li:hover, .sf-menu > li li.sfHover,
.sf-menu > li li a:focus, .sf-menu > li li a:hover, .sf-menu > li li a:active {
    background: #EEE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the style of:

```
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color:          #FFF;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

The white text colour appears to be coming from there.